# Conditional return signature depending on a runtime boolean value

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I have tried to check whether the `isArray` is true or false and conditionally return either `LocationQueryValue` or `LocationQueryValue[]` but it didn't work out - the returned type would always evaluate to `LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]` no matter if `isArray` was passed as `true` or `false`.

For example, I want it to:

1. Return `LocationQueryValue[]` if the passed `isArray` is true
2. Return `LocationQueryValue` if the passed `isArray` is false

```
type QueryValue<T> = T extends undefined
    ? never
    : T extends true
    ? LocationQueryValue[]
    : LocationQueryValue;

export const useRouteQuery = <
    K extends string,
    O extends { isArray?: boolean; clearPage?: boolean }
>(
    key: K,
    options: O
) => {
    const parsedOptions = {
        isArray: false,
        clearPage: false,
        ...options
    };
    const route = useRoute();

    const getQueryValue = (): QueryValue<typeof options.isArray> => {
        const value = route.query[key];
        if (value && parsedOptions?.isArray) {
            return toArray(value);
        }
        return value;
    };

    const queryValue = computed(getQueryValue);

    return { queryValue };
};


const { queryValue: firstVal } = useRouteQuery("test", { isArray: true, clearPage: true }); // === LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]
const { queryValue: secondVal } = useRouteQuery("test2", { isArray: false, clearPage: true }); // Same: === LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]
```

Here is the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpQnBW) sample. Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: ① Please [edit] the question to clearly and explicitly indicate the problem; "it didn't work out" isn't really sufficient for it to be a [mre].  ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlyeOm) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry for the lack of information, I copied the text from one of the comments I added on the question from StackOverflow. The solution you provided is absolutely what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll work on writing up an answer, but could you please [edit] the question to make it clear what the issue is for future readers?

Comment: Eh, I would use overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your version is that when you have an expression of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) object type, like `options` of type `O`, and then you index into it with a specific, non-generic key like `"isArray"`, the compiler immediately widens the generic type to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  So the type of `options.isArray` is seen as the specific type `boolean | undefined` instead of anything generic.  That's not *wrong*, but it isn't helpful inside the type `QueryValue<typeof options.isArray>`.

What you really wanted is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  That is, not `typeof (options.isArray)` (which is what `typeof options.isArray` is parsed as), but `(typeof options)["isArray"]`.  And since `typeof options` is just `O`, that means you want the type `QueryValue<O["isArray"]>`.

If you make that change and only that change, your calls will immediately start working as desired:

```
export const useRouteQuery = <
    K extends string,
    O extends { isArray?: boolean; clearPage?: boolean }
>(key: K, options: O) => {
    // ✂ ⋯ ✂
    const getQueryValue = (): QueryValue<O["isArray"]> => { /* ✂ ⋯ ✂ */ }
    const queryValue = computed(getQueryValue);
    return { queryValue };
};

const { queryValue: firstVal } = 
  useRouteQuery("test", { isArray: true, clearPage: true });
// const firstVal: ComputedRef<LocationQueryValue[]> 
const { queryValue: secondVal } = 
  useRouteQuery("test2", { isArray: false, clearPage: true });
// const secondVal: ComputedRef<LocationQueryValue>
```

Hooray!

---

So, that's the answer to the question as asked.  But if you do that you'll immediately get compiler errors inside the implementation of `getQueryValue`:

```
const getQueryValue = (): QueryValue<O["isArray"]> => {
    const value = route.query[key];
    if (value && parsedOptions?.isArray) {
        return toArray(value); // error! 
        // Type '(string | null)[]' is not assignable 
        // to type 'QueryValue<O["isArray"]>'
    }
    return value; // error! 
    // Type 'LocationQueryValue | LocationQueryValue[]' is 
    // not assignable to type 'QueryValue<O["isArray"]>'.
};
```

Oops.  That's because `QueryValue<O["isArray"]>` is a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and the compiler really has no idea what non-generic values might be compatible with such types.  The check like `if (value && parsedOptions?.isArray)` might have some effect on `value` or `parsedOptions` but it does nothing to `O`, so the compiler can't verify your implementation as safe.  There's an open feature request for something better here at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), but for now there's nothing much better than using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or other techniques to loosen the type checking to make it possibly-too-permissive instead of possibly-too-restrictive.

One might write

```
type Q = QueryValue<(typeof options)["isArray"]>;
const getQueryValue = (): Q => {
    const value = route.query[key];
    if (value && parsedOptions?.isArray) {
        return toArray(value) as Q;
    }
    return value as Q;
};
```

to give the relevant type a name like `Q` and then just assert that each returned value is of that type.  This will suppress errors (and there are definitely other ways to do that; you could just write `as any` and not bother with defining `Q`, or use overloads, etc) and let you move on with your life.  Just remember that you're responsible for the implementation matching the call signature, because the compiler cannot be.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDCBBKUCGBPOAzKERwBEANhACZoDOAFgPSIroaEDcAUKJLHAN5wDG+MAFcYAUzJwAvjjwFCAN2FjWHcNHh9hlMQCUIosdNn4iSsQFo8hqKs4aEGMEb4AZCPzQxgEAHYBFZSgMADU0YmVjXFNFZSsDcVt2Nl80EDFKMDR+IwAxYAAPXOgAYXDiMShKXjY4OsdnOEDK0PDlAB4AFQA+OABeOE64MQLxXzJq4XGxbGBfCVr6pYB+OHmFSsWluoAuQeHRsXHqmChlLe3V909vP2bgsIixAG0AXQulveuvHwCg1qeySWIy48EEvko8G0egSYnuWAG7Q+9QA0gcxhM4JCoHMAOYAGmRdQA8uijpi+MBKIxMMs9gAjCAQCpoXwsAQsqAABTQuLEdLgjOZYlZ0gu3QAFES4ABrMQYPYownbeoQMC3CF7YkXACU-V6PGl4MhcCyVQkxPVv2qA0NKpVVJpCpw4R0yvtS34nJ5fL22FdYndHrqADow2qNZRpVJ2B7jfBrOJ+nBofpDBKdUD7fG4HyYPDHpEBhm9gW2mJ2sTnoRHahMIRXr0+gbpZ6-CaFOXk4mxCGAI7-Z5yjCvWPBurAbBwCWdp5wABk89NaHNZEtkeWIdrTD1dvH2ygYhgwigvgQyDrGBn5czcFotGGqGgAEI4K37ffBk4jAByCXYvE4AAHzWYRiGIHU3h-OAqTWCB4CoShgFxVJ6QqN9922T9EAaX8yyeStq23etGx-d86ikci4EPY9TzgWdlHZT9KjwKBXyoz9Om-OAf2+DV8MiEC+N+ASXleaDYI4h9fHguBEOQ1D0JwmBuJ-UTCJralLwbbofxDaMsxVHMBxaQsjAGQRwEMMgJTzUTMzYaUaJPM8+BMh4uxjC4vIuHM3P+My-WAKoYEeYwBlTWF4QlQhxEhQh8V4GCtKYPZTmURKvRFbleTENKziMKQHKWT8c1mELHj2EohGs3QZnaYS7gC8s3m6Xz200OB3IBZQ9h0cEyDCmQIp0NNxGi2KMhgAAmBKkuI51-WIN0OWyn08oQArpGK+pSo6rExAGyq4GqqzxDIOrsAajwfia0zyzathKJSNIMiyHIv2cJBKB0WBrU6CAAGVhDAMBDx+gBRJ8qhqJYVMadSemTIYRgxSZplmeYyGlVZ1k2D09hRw5jk284PSuG7+Oap43mlL5KZE6nGMc4EClBAR9siwx4WTJEPTRVHyWqADfAJaVSUFknKRS2kGSZFk2VWld1oFIUFbFJZJWlYdFSDbYI2tLVdX1WHs32s0dDXK122TPdxwWv0Az1uNvVyx3lsDKiwxDA32wMo19p7ZMufEDNDO2eGjH8ZN1IlSOICnX2IUgzSnR0scjP2uymfM6cdVLE27eDHMGNznt+0HYdRyoydp1Lhclwti1rYhTcFt3KilmcuiGEva8nj1Kgmgz4NKMw7uz3rof-BHpYfLjfburM5NLJEc7bKPezw67o8XKSpfPJHnz2ohTqD6eIKKvCcKU1GqL-hiuKYDm6WnXyjKlZy31ScKna6j20+OBgqQmOqdNeEhLrXRuIze6NNGwnxNP5WBvUDpHWvsNW+MJuYP0mpCWaiVX6XnditLKys3Y-22iPABJp+p+EGuEKqNVzqQMan8ZBYg2qUSAA)